# Different result when I try read excelRange

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

A have a problem when I want to read excel cell range. I read same cell on same index repeatedly. And I get different result.

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo("list_INN_OGRN_org_20180928.xlsx");
using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
{   
    var workSheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[2];
    var x = workSheet.Cells[2, 1, 2, 10]; // x = {C3}
    var y = workSheet.Cells[2, 1, 2, 10]; // y = {A2:J2}
    var z = workSheet.Cells[2, 1, 2, 10]; // z = {A2:J2}
    int rowsOffset = 2;
    int endColumn = 10;
    var headerCells = workSheet.Cells[rowsOffset, 1, rowsOffset, endColumn]; // headerCells  = {A1}
}
```

[list_INN_OGRN_org_20180928.xlsx](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/files/2541527/list_INN_OGRN_org_20180928.xlsx)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the step debug mode in VisualStudio 2017 Professional, when i don't set a breakpoint my program work correctly.